# How to redirect users from a site to one page with a condition. Blazor server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How do I redirect users in blazor? I want to make some kind of global filter, for example, if the site is disabled in the settings, then redirect users to the "/ shutdown" page. I only found AuthorizeRoute, but it does not suit all my purposes, there are some ideas or libraries for working with routing in blazor. (I am using blazor server)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0

You can inject `NavigationManager` into your component and call `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` if your condition passes.

To perform this check no matter where the user has navigated to, you can perform this check in `App.razor` or even in your `Layout.razor`.

```cs
@inject NavigationManager Nav

<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    ...
</Router>

@code {
    if (Settings["disabled"] == true) {
        Nav.NavigateTo("/shutdown");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to be mean, but the OP should probably go through all of Blazor documentation, starting with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: This solution did not work for me, since the user was first shown the initial page, and after 1-3 seconds the page I needed was already shown. I would like to show an intermediate page (something like an animation page that says: expect redirects). After much thought, I came to the conclusion to use this in MainLoyaut. Initially, I thought that Blazor has the same routing filters as the AspNet core. thanks anyway.